# Replacing specials character with plain white space in c#?

Tags: c#, replace, char

I'm trying to replace a special char with plain white space in a utf-8 file. The problem is when I try the space char or null, the special char if replaced but with some other special char, like a diamond with a question mark or a small square.

Here's the code I'm using to replace one of the chars:

> content = content.Replace((char)0XA0, '\0');

I have also tried:

> content = content.Replace((char)0XA0, ' ');

and it doesnt work either

The files I'm dealing with can get pretty large so parsing one char at a time isn't workable.

Looking for any advice on how to go about getting this to work.

Thanks

Comment: Chances are your reading or writing code is wrong... Also replacing something with `\0` is probably bad idea - your title seem to imply `' '` (character with code `32` or `0x20`, not `0x0`).

Comment: yup I edited the entry I did also try ' ' and it didnt work.

Comment: You are not showing code that reads/writes the file...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried content = content.Replace((char)0XA0, ' ');?

Comment: out of everything i tried, this was the simplest working solution i found. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with special utf-8 characters, you would be happy use ushort uint instead of char, as utf-8 characters can be anything about one to four bytes.

Answer (score 0):

`0xA0` is not a valid UTF-8 representation of a character.  The actual the UTF-8 representation of the character uA0 is 194 160 (or 0xC2 0xA0).

you can use a string literal instead

```
content = content.Replace('\u00A0', ' ');
```

UTF codes higher than 127 will be represented as surrogate pairs when using UTF-8.

Comment: Interesting. But 0x0A is in the utf-8 (when I open the file in Notepad++ that is what shows) file and I must keep it utf-8 because there are chinese chars in it which are utf-8. But I will try yourr suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: .NET stores strings internally in utf-16. If you're at the point that you're manipulating the content using strings, then they're utf-16. At that point you need to ensure that when you're writing it out back to a file, it's being encoded in utf-8.